# Asp.net MVC- get resized image from requested url get 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have some image file in server in image folder
I want to get resized version of image when requested image from url does not exist.
I have wirtten code to re-size image from original image.
but I don't know how to do this when request sent from url, for example
when i Type `http://example.com/Image/a_140_140.jpg` if there is file with name a.jpg create a resized image with name `a_140_140.jpg` with my code and return it to client.
but now i get `404 Error`
please Help me how to do this work to never get 404 error.

I don't add any more route in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer use the below solution:
I use `Asp.net MVC` but with some changes you can use this for every site
 1. add below rows to web.config

```
  <httpErrors>
     <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/Http404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

2. add this route to Routeconfig.cs

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            "404-PageNotFound",
            "{*url}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Http404" });
```

3. for controller code use this code:

```
 [MySite.WebUI.Infrastructure.AjaxCrawlable]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            if (url.LastIndexOf('.') != -1)
            {
                string extention = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower();
                var extentionList = new string[] { "jpg", "png", "gif", "tif" };
                if (extentionList.Contains(extention))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                        string extentionnow = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
                        var _mainpath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf("/"));
                        string _mainfileName = FileName.Substring(0, (FileName.LastIndexOf('_')));
                        int _imagesize = int.Parse(FileName.Substring((FileName.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)));
                        if (_imagesize != null || _imagesize != 0)
                        {
                            var t = Resize.FindResizeImage("~" + _mainpath + "/" + _mainfileName + extentionnow, _imagesize);
                            return new RedirectResult(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return View();
                    }

                }
            }
            else
                return View();
            return View();
        }
```

4. add this class for resize images

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

```
namespace MySite.WebUI.Models
{
    public static class Resize
    {
        public static string FindResizeImage(string path, int size)
        {

            var _serverpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_serverpath))
            {
                var Extention = Path.GetExtension(path);
                var _pathresize = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(".")) + "_" + size.ToString() + Extention;
                var _serverpathresize = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_pathresize);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(_serverpathresize))
                {
                    return _pathresize.Substring(1, _pathresize.Length - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Resize.Resizeing(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path), HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_pathresize), size);
                    return _pathresize;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static void Resizeing(string imageFile, string outputFile, int size)
        {
            using (var srcImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile))
            {
                using (var newImage = new Bitmap(size, size))
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, size, size));
                    newImage.Save(outputFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `Resize.FindResizeImage` method?

Comment: I own complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to use 404 error forwarding in IIS?